# Training Loop of RNN returning the same loss after each epoch

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a RNN from scratch, with the help of this repository (https://github.com/nicklashansen/rnn_lstm_from_scratch/tree/master), but the training loss after each epoch stays the same. The code for the training loop is as follows:

```
# Hyper-parameters
num_epochs = 1000

# Initialize a new network
params = init_rnn(hidden_size=hidden_size, vocab_size=vocab_size)

# Initialize hidden state as zeros
hidden_state = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1))

# Track loss
training_loss, validation_loss = [], []

def check_if_params_updated(old_params, new_params):
    # This function checks if two sets of parameters are different
    for old_param, new_param in zip(old_params, new_params):
        if not np.array_equal(old_param, new_param):
            return True  # Parameters have been updated
    return False  # Parameters have not been updated


# For each epoch
for i in range(num_epochs):
    
    # Track loss
    epoch_training_loss = 0
    epoch_validation_loss = 0
    
     # For each sentence in validation set
    for inputs, targets in val_loader:
        
        # One-hot encode input and target sequence
        inputs_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(inputs, vocab_size)
        targets_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(targets, vocab_size)
        
        # Re-initialize hidden state
        hidden_state = np.zeros_like(hidden_state)

        # Forward pass
        outputs, hidden_states = forward_pass(inputs_one_hot, hidden_state, params)

        # Backward pass
        loss, _ = backward_pass(inputs_one_hot, outputs, hidden_states, targets_one_hot, params)
        
        # Update loss
        epoch_validation_loss += loss
    
    # For each sentence in training set
    for inputs, targets in train_loader:
        
        # One-hot encode input and target sequence
        inputs_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(inputs, vocab_size)
        targets_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(targets, vocab_size)
        
        # Re-initialize hidden state
        hidden_state = np.zeros_like(hidden_state)

        # Forward pass
        outputs, hidden_states = forward_pass(inputs_one_hot, hidden_state, params)

        # Backward pass
        loss, grads = backward_pass(inputs_one_hot, outputs, hidden_states, targets_one_hot, params)
        print(inputs_one_hot.shape)
        
        if np.isnan(loss):
            raise ValueError('Gradients have vanished/exploded!')
        
        # Update parameters
        params = update_parameters(params, grads, lr=1e-3)
        
        # Update loss
        epoch_training_loss += loss
        
    # Save loss for plot
    training_loss.append(epoch_training_loss/len(training_set))
    validation_loss.append(epoch_validation_loss/len(validation_set))

    # Print loss every 100 epochs
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch {i}, training loss: {training_loss[-1]}, validation loss: {validation_loss[-1]}')


# Get first sentence in test set
inputs, targets = test_set[1]

# One-hot encode input and target sequence
inputs_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(inputs, vocab_size)
targets_one_hot = one_hot_encode_sequence(targets, vocab_size)

# Initialize hidden state as zeros
hidden_state = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1))

# Forward pass
outputs, hidden_states = forward_pass(inputs_one_hot, hidden_state, params)
output_sentence = [idx_to_word[np.argmax(output)] for output in outputs]
print('Input sentence:')
print(inputs)

print('\nTarget sequence:')
print(targets)

print('\nPredicted sequence:')
print([idx_to_word[np.argmax(output)] for output in outputs])

# Plot training and validation loss
epoch = np.arange(len(training_loss))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(epoch, training_loss, 'r', label='Training loss',)
plt.plot(epoch, validation_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Epoch'), plt.ylabel('NLL')
plt.show()
```

I have tried checking if my parameters are updating and they are, also tried checking the gradient and they are not exponentially small. The loss decreases after each iteration, but the loss of the total epoch increases. You can find the full code, which includes the forward and backward pass in the repository(https://github.com/dangerdude237/RNN_From_Scratch).

Edit: So got the problem of the loss staying the same after each epoch fixed, I needed to change the loss function. But now the loss after each epoch increases.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are dividing total loss by the number of batches in validation set but you are not doing this for training set. you should update the code accordingly: `epoch_training_loss += loss training_loss.append(epoch_training_loss / len(train_loader)) validation_loss.append(epoch_validation_loss / len(val_loader))`
if this doesn't work then there might be an issue in your hidden stage initialization, you should initialize hidden stage as zero at the beginning of every start of epoch. `hidden_state = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1))`

Comment: Hi Mansiba, actually I have still yet to implement batches, instead, I am taking the whole training set and updating the parameters after each sample.